# To calculate the multiple operation at a time in android for calculator

Tags: java, android

I want to do multiple operation in calculator for example:`2+3*3/7`. 
How to do that. can any one help me. The single operation of the calculator work.

How to calculate multiple operations in one `editText`. This code is added on equal button click method.

Below is my code:

```
  btnEqualto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 

    {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) 

                      {

                     String str2 = edtxt.getText().toString();

                       if (buttonPressed.equals("+")) 

            {
                Log.e(TAG,"dot operation="+strDot);


                if (strDot.equals(".")) 

                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "If Codition :");


                    String str1[] = str2.split("[+]");

                    Log.e(TAG,"str1 ="+str1);

                    String strVal11 = str1[0];

                    String strVal22 = str1[1];

        Log.e(TAG, "strValues  :" + strVal11 + " & " + strVal22);

                    Double xx = Double.parseDouble(strVal11);

                    Double yy = Double.parseDouble(strVal22);

       Log.e(TAG, "Value of x :" + xx + "  AND y : " + yy);

                    Log.e(TAG, "dot operation");


                    Double result = xx + yy;

                    Log.e(TAG, "Result  :" + result);

                    edtxt.setText(result + "");


                    Log.e(TAG, "VAlue of Result :" + edtxt);

                }

                else

                {

                    Log.e(TAG, "If Codition :"+strVal2);

                    strDot = "";

                    String str1[] = str2.split("[+]");

                    strVal1 = str1[0];

                    strVal2 = str1[1];


                          Log.e(TAG, "Esle Condition 4 Pllus strValues  :" + strVal1 + " & " + strVal2);


                    x = Integer.parseInt(strVal1);

                    y = Integer.parseInt(strVal2);

            Log.e(TAG, "Value of x :" + x + "  AND y : " + y);

                    int result = x + y;

                    Log.e(TAG, "Result  :" + result);

                    edtxt.setText(result + "");
                                                    Log.e(TAG, "VAlue of Result :" + edtxt);

                }

            }

          }

         }

         );
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the text from the Eclipse LogCat window (the entire red part).

Comment: And don't suppress 'unused' warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Try exp4j: [a simple mathematical expression parser for java..](http://www.objecthunter.net/tinybo/blog/articles/86)

> exp4j takes a mathematical term in human readable infix notation and
>   evaluate it's result by first converting the input through Dijkstra's
>   Shunting Yard Algorithm to postfix (RNP) notation and evaluating the
>   postfix term by a simple Stack Algorithm.

Try it and see if this works for you..